# How to know bounced email with nodemailer?

Tags: smtp, nodemailer

I use nodemailer to send an email. I'd like to know when an email bounces. I've set up an SMTP server for the domain bounce.mydomain.com (I've tried it, and it works fine).

However, when I send a message with nodemailer and the email bounces, the email is returned to the sender (emailTo in the example below) instead of bounceId=${randomUID}@bounce.mydomain.com.

Do you see the problem?

Thank you in advance.

```
const info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: `<${emailFrom}>`,
        to: emailTo,
        subject,
        text,
        html:text,
        messageId:`${randomUUID}`,
        envelope:{
            from:`bounceId=${randomUUID}@bounce.mydomain.com`,
            to: emailTo
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally find out what was wrong here is a correction (the *to* field in the *envelope* must be the receiver of the bounced message) :

```
const info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: `<${emailFrom}>`,
        to: emailTo,
        subject,
        text,
        html:text,
        messageId:`${randomUUID}`,
        envelope:{
            from:"Daemon <deamon@$mydomain.com>",
            to: `bounceId=${randomUUID}@bounce.mydomain.com`
        }

})
```